# SOAP Security negotiation Error while calling Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 sdk IOrganizationServiceProxy web service

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm-2011

we have a virtual machine in our company that contains sqlserver and crm 2011 installed on It which we use It for testing our codes and I have written a simple webservice to call the sdk IOrganizationServieProxy webservice . on this Virtual machine my code works perfeclty with no error . BUT here is the situation : we have two other virtual machines , on one of them the sql server is installed and on the other one crm is installed and configured . the crm works fine but when I try to use my web service which calls the crm sdk IOrganizationServieProxy  webservice webmethods I get the following errorr , any Ideas what could be wrong ? thanks in advance for anyone who answears this question .

```
    System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: SOAP security negotiation with &#39;http://localhost/KN/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc&#39; for target &#39;http://localhost/KN/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc&#39; failed. See inner exception for more details. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WindowsSspiNegotiation.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, ChannelBinding channelbinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy protectionPolicy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.GetNextOutgoingMessage(Message incomingMessage, T negotiationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultipleCore(QueryBase query)
   at KNCRMSearchWebService.searchContactsByNameAndFamilyName(String cl, String Name, String Family)
```

and here is an image from my visualstudio debug mode which shows the error :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It may not apply, but I have run into problems when the URL I used didn't match the WCF bindings set in the CRM Deployment Manager.

For instance, a server named "MyCRMServer" might be listening on port 80 at:

```
http://MyCrmServer/
```

...but if I had changed my CRM Server in Deployment Manager to url "crm.myCompany.com" then I have to use this URL to access web services:

```
http://crm.myCompany.com/
```